Fischer mode and time forfeits
Fischer mode theoretically makes it "impossible" that you can't win
a won game "just" because lack of time. Of course, it doesn't help
in complicated situations where you simply need more than 30 seconds
but already used up your 1.5 hours before the 40th move.
Is there a statistic (maybe a Megabase; of course noone guarantees
you that a flag forfeit is properly indicated in the PGN) about
the percentage of games with overstepped time before and after Fischer mode
in standard tournament games? (Or in absence of that, a "felt" number
by active arbiters?)
